Ubuntu 24.04 apt install would remove ubuntu-desktop, how to avoid this?
When I try to install gnome-tweaks via apt, it would remove some critical packages like ubuntu-desktop. I've searched around google and asked chatgpt for a while but got no right answer. How can I fix this?
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  attr cpdb-backend-cups gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomeautoar-0.1 gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-4.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-6.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-13 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma4-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-webkit-6.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gjs gkbd-capplet gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-shell-pomodoro-data gnome-startup-applications gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data gstreamer1.0-pipewire gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf ibverbs-providers libblkid-dev libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libbrotli-dev
  libbz2-dev libcephfs2 libcpdb-frontend2 libcpdb2 libcue2 libdatrie-dev libdbus-1-dev libdeflate-dev libegl-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libepoxy-dev libfontconfig-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype-dev libfribidi-dev libgcrypt20-dev libgfapi0 libgfrpc0
  libgfxdr0 libgjs0g libgl-dev libgles-dev libgles1 libglib2.0-dev-bin libglusterfs0 libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd-dev libglx-dev libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgpg-error-dev libgphoto2-l10n libgraphite2-dev libgsf-1-114
  libgsf-1-common libharfbuzz-cairo0 libharfbuzz-subset0 libibverbs1 libjbig-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblerc-dev liblzma-dev libmount-dev libmozjs-115-0t64 libopengl-dev libpcre2-dev libpcre2-posix3 libperl5.36 libpixman-1-dev
  libpng-dev libpng-tools libportal-gtk4-1 libpsl-dev libpython3.11-dev librados2 librdmacm1 libselinux1-dev libsepol-dev libsharpyuv-dev libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libtext-engine-0.1-0 libthai-dev libtiff-dev libtiffxx6 liburing2 libwayland-bin libwayland-dev
  libwebp-dev libwebpdecoder3 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxklavier16 libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxtst-dev
  libzstd-dev nautilus-data pango1.0-tools perl-modules-5.36 python3-dateutil python3-deprecation python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-software-properties python3.11-dev samba samba-ad-provision samba-vfs-modules switcheroo-control
  tdb-tools ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon ubuntu-advantage-tools unattended-upgrades uuid-dev wayland-protocols x11proto-record-dev x11proto-xext-dev xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apt apt-utils at-spi2-core brltty cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc duplicity evolution-data-server gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0
  gir1.2-girepository-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-4.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-4.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gjs gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-online-accounts gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-pomodoro-data gnutls-bin gstreamer1.0-pipewire gtk-update-icon-cache heif-gdk-pixbuf heif-thumbnailer hplip
  hplip-data libabsl20220623t64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libapt-pkg6.0t64 libasound2-dev libasound2t64 libatk-adaptor libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 libatk1.0-0t64 libatspi2.0-0t64 libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcamel-1.2-64t64 libcanberra-gtk3-0t64 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcanberra0t64 libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcolord-gtk4-1t64 libcommon-sense-perl libcups2t64 libcupsimage2t64
  libdb5.3t64 libdevel-callchecker-perl libdmapsharing-4.0-3t64 libebackend-1.2-11t64 libebook-1.2-21t64 libebook-contacts-1.2-4t64 libecal-2.0-3 libedata-book-1.2-27t64 libedata-cal-2.0-2t64 libedataserver-1.2-27t64 libedataserverui-1.2-4t64
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgck-2-2 libgcr-4-4 libgdbm-compat4t64 libgdbm6t64 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdm1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl libglib2.0-0t64 libglib2.0-dev-bin
  libgnome-bg-4-2t64 libgnome-desktop-3-20t64 libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 libgnome-rr-4-2t64 libgnutls-dane0t64 libgnutls30t64 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-backend-1.0-2 libgom-1.0-0t64 libgpgme11t64 libgpod-common libgpod4t64 libgsound0t64 libgtk-3-0t64
  libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-4-1 libgudev-1.0-0 libgweather-4-0t64 libharfbuzz-cairo0 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz-subset0 libharfbuzz0b libhogweed6t64 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libical3t64 libjson-xs-perl libldb2
  liblirc-client0t64 liblocale-gettext-perl libmozjs-115-0t64 libmtp-runtime libmtp9t64 libnautilus-extension4 libnet-dbus-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnettle8t64 libnotify4 libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0
  libpangoxft-1.0-0 libparams-classify-perl libperl5.38t64 libphonenumber8 libpipewire-0.3-0t64 libpipewire-0.3-modules libpng-dev libpng-tools libpng16-16t64 libprotobuf32t64 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.12-dev libpython3.12-minimal
  libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12t64 libqpdf29t64 libreadline8t64 librhythmbox-core10 libroc0.3 librsync2t64 libsane-hpaio libsecret-1-0 libsmbclient0 libsnmp40t64 libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-modules libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl
  libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtevent0t64 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtirpc3t64 libtracker-sparql-3.0-0 libuv1-dev libuv1t64 libvariable-magic-perl libxml-parser-perl libxmlb2 nautilus-data pango1.0-tools perl perl-base perl-modules-5.38
  pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-brotli python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-cssselect python3-cups
  python3-dbus python3-deprecated python3-dev python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gpg python3-ldb python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-pikepdf python3-pil python3-pyaudio python3-samba python3-software-properties
  python3-systemd python3-talloc python3-tdb python3-venv python3-wrapt python3-yaml python3.12 python3.12-dev python3.12-minimal python3.12-venv rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules user-session-migration
Suggested packages:
  apt-doc aptitude | synaptic | wajig brltty-speechd brltty-x11 console-braille unicode-cldr-core cups-pdf smbclient inetutils-inetd | inet-superserver python3-boto3 ncftp lftp tahoe-lafs python3-swiftclient par2 evolution gnome-software
  | gnome-packagekit gnome-user-share realmd gnome-shell-extension-prefs | gnome-shell-extension-manager hplip-doc hplip-gui python3-notify2 libasound2-doc libasound2-plugins libfont-freetype-perl libcanberra-gtk0 gdbm-l10n libxml-libxml-perl
  low-memory-monitor lirc libscalar-number-perl graphicsmagick perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl libtap-harness-archive-perl pulseaudio-utils python3-doc python3-tk python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc python-lxml-doc
  python-pil-doc python-pyaudio-doc python3.12-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gnome-codec-install rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony winbind heimdal-clients
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gdm3 gnome-characters gnome-shell gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-manager gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant gnome-shell-pomodoro
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit libabsl20220623 libapt-pkg6.0 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-dev libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-dev libatspi2.0-0 libatspi2.0-dev libcairo2-dev libcamel-1.2-64 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra0 libcolord-gtk4-1 libcups2
  libcupsimage2 libdb5.3 libdmapsharing-4.0-3 libebackend-1.2-11 libebook-1.2-21 libebook-contacts-1.2-4 libedata-book-1.2-27 libedata-cal-2.0-2 libedataserver-1.2-27 libedataserverui-1.2-4 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libgnome-bg-4-2 libgnome-desktop-3-20 libgnome-desktop-4-2 libgnome-rr-4-2 libgnutls-dane0 libgnutls30 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgme11 libgpod4 libgsound0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev libgweather-4-0 libharfbuzz-dev libhogweed6
  libical3 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev liblirc-client0 libmozjs-115-0 libmtp9 libnettle8 libpango1.0-dev libpipewire-0.3-0 libpng16-16 libprotobuf32 libqpdf29 libreadline8 librsync2 libsecret-1-dev libsmbclient libsnmp40 libsoup2.4-dev libtevent0
  libtirpc3 libuv1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev nautilus nautilus-share packagekit packagekit-tools python3-distutils python3.11-venv software-properties-common software-properties-gtk tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-session ubuntu-settings yaru-theme-gtk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-girepository-2.0 gnome-tweaks heif-gdk-pixbuf heif-thumbnailer libabsl20220623t64 libapt-pkg6.0t64 libasound2t64 libatk-bridge2.0-0t64 libatk1.0-0t64 libatspi2.0-0t64 libcamel-1.2-64t64 libcanberra-gtk3-0t64 libcanberra0t64 libcolord-gtk4-1t64
  libcups2t64 libcupsimage2t64 libdb5.3t64 libdmapsharing-4.0-3t64 libebackend-1.2-11t64 libebook-1.2-21t64 libebook-contacts-1.2-4t64 libecal-2.0-3 libedata-book-1.2-27t64 libedata-cal-2.0-2t64 libedataserver-1.2-27t64 libedataserverui-1.2-4t64
  libgck-2-2 libgcr-4-4 libgdbm-compat4t64 libgdbm6t64 libglib2.0-0t64 libgnome-bg-4-2t64 libgnome-desktop-3-20t64 libgnome-desktop-4-2t64 libgnome-rr-4-2t64 libgnutls-dane0t64 libgnutls30t64 libgoa-backend-1.0-2 libgom-1.0-0t64 libgpgme11t64
  libgpod4t64 libgsound0t64 libgtk-3-0t64 libgweather-4-0t64 libhogweed6t64 libical3t64 liblirc-client0t64 libmozjs-115-0t64 libmtp9t64 libnettle8t64 libperl5.38t64 libpipewire-0.3-0t64 libpng16-16t64 libprotobuf32t64 libpython3.12-dev
  libpython3.12-minimal libpython3.12-stdlib libpython3.12t64 libqpdf29t64 libreadline8t64 libroc0.3 librsync2t64 libsmbclient0 libsnmp40t64 libtevent0t64 libtirpc3t64 libuv1t64 perl-modules-5.38 python3-cssselect python3-deprecated python3-wrapt
  python3.12 python3.12-dev python3.12-minimal python3.12-venv user-session-migration
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils at-spi2-core brltty cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc duplicity evolution-data-server gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-4.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-4.0 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-secret-1 gjs gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-pomodoro-data gnutls-bin gstreamer1.0-pipewire gtk-update-icon-cache hplip hplip-data libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libasound2-dev libatk-adaptor
  libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-gobject2 libcairo-perl libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl libcommon-sense-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdm1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl libglib2.0-dev-bin libgoa-1.0-0b libgpod-common libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-4-1
  libgudev-1.0-0 libharfbuzz-cairo0 libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz-subset0 libharfbuzz0b libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libjson-xs-perl libldb2 liblocale-gettext-perl libmtp-runtime libnautilus-extension4 libnet-dbus-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl libnotify4 libpackage-stash-xs-perl libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libparams-classify-perl libphonenumber8 libpipewire-0.3-modules libpng-dev libpng-tools libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib
  librhythmbox-core10 libsane-hpaio libsecret-1-0 libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-modules libsub-identify-perl libsub-name-perl libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtracker-sparql-3.0-0 libuv1-dev libvariable-magic-perl
  libxml-parser-perl libxmlb2 nautilus-data pango1.0-tools perl perl-base pipewire pipewire-alsa pipewire-bin pipewire-pulse printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-splix python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-brotli
  python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-cups python3-dbus python3-dev python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gpg python3-ldb python3-lxml python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-netifaces python3-pikepdf python3-pil python3-pyaudio python3-samba
  python3-software-properties python3-systemd python3-talloc python3-tdb python3-venv python3-yaml rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
161 upgraded, 76 newly installed, 93 to remove and 557 not upgraded.
Need to get 107 MB of archives.
After this operation, 26.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 


My system info is here:
http://paste.debian.net/1326959/

For some reason, this looks like a very mismanaged system. Maybe you should explain exactly which things you did to your system to get it into this state? I would recommend a total reinstall based on the information you have given so far.

Your details do NOT match a noble or 24.04 LTS; your details show you using an unsupported 23.10 kernel (which was used awhile by 22.04 systems too) so did you recently release-upgrade and haven't yet rebooted etc?  Some details of what you've done may help, as your details do not match a 24.04 system that is in good health.

I upgraded to 24.04 few months ago, and recently because I can't install virtualbox, I updated my source list to 23.10 (based on chatgpt advice) and did apt update & apt upgrade. Still can't install virtualbox. Then I changed the source list back to 24.04. And this is what's happening now. Is there anything I can do to rescue?

"Based on chatgpt advice". Yes, this is when you uncritically takes the advice of a dumb robot. What you did most likely destroyed your system. I advice a full reinstall.

Or you can do a hail mary and carry on with the upgrade command and see what happens - but be prepared to do a reinstall either way.

Thanks @ArturMeinild, I will be prepared and give it a shot, that was dumb of me. I don't understand much about how these things works

Well, good luck anyway - hopefully this was a lesson you'll remember onwards from now.

If you just want to install gnome-tweaks, you can try
apt download gnome-tweaks;
dpkg -i gnome-tweaks*.deb


I prepared a bootable usb and was ready to reinstall the whole system, but after I tried 'sudo apt dist-upgrade' and reboot, everything works fine now. I guess I was lucky haha

The touchscreen stopped working though, but the system is fine. I just installed virtualbox and upgraded all the packages.

Just FYI, but if you'd release-upgraded to noble or 24.04; then added sources for mantic (23.10) I would expect many packages to revert back to mantic as the deb package tools (apt, dpkg etc) need to be forced to go to older versions, thus I'd expect minimal effects except for rare outliers that would show up on rare occasion in unusual issues like you add in your question... Queries such as apt policy I mention would let you detect those (from lack or or inappropriate sources) & allow you to correct manually. Artur's re-install approach achieved this quicker I suspect

The result from the uname command (first on your paste) is key issue.. you're using an unsupported kernel & thus should keep your system offline if you're still using 6.5 (from 23.10!!  as its EOL & not getting security fixes patched)...  Artur's approach would correct such security problems///

This is the system info now: https://paste.debian.net/1326979, the kernel has been updated to 6.8.0, I think it should be working fine now
